# Query String param and value removed when accessing Lighting App Page

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, oauth2

As part of a custom `OAuth2` flow, the user is being redirected back to a `Lightning App Page` with URL:

`https://x-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/namespace__Page_Name?state=q765wYYgnvzVAsod&code=c1BF-iddZNkD1aMxVYp8p5smeAQUxITQUesC3Q_ggYHyNJzm`

With a few query string params `state` and `code`.

But the page does a refresh before it loads, and the query string params are removed.

I want to access the values in `state` and `code` from the custom `LWC` component on the page?

I have tried looking in `CurrentPageReference`:

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";
```

Using:

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
currentPageReference;

connectedCallback() {
    console.log("state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.currentPageReference.state));
}
```

But the `state` object is empty `{}`

And, I've tried getting the value from the URL:

```
connectedCallback() {
    const param = "code";
    const paramValue = this.getUrlParamValue(window.location.href, param);
    console.log(param + ": " + paramValue);
}

getUrlParamValue(url, key) {
    return new URL(url).searchParams.get(key);
}
```

But nothing.

How can I access the values in `state` and `code` from the custom `LWC` component on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a `Visualforce` page to capture the query string params and redirect:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">

    <head>
        <title>OAuth 2.0 Redirect</title>
    </head>
    <script>
    
    window.onload = onLoad;
    
    function onLoad() {
        const code = getUrlParamValue(window.location.href, 'code');
        location.href = '/lightning/n/namespace__Page_Name?namespace__code=' + code;
    }

    function getUrlParamValue(url, key) {
        return new URL(url).searchParams.get(key);
    }

    </script>
    <body>
        Redirecting...
    </body>
</apex:page>
```